# how storm hdfs write to different file path

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm

I am not understanding how I would do like this

For example, I have bolt A that after some computation has somevalue1, somevalue2, and somevalueX.

It wants to send to hdfs like this:

`somevalue1 -> /somevalue1/path-hdfs/somevalue1.txt`

`somevalue2 -> /somevalue2/path-hdfs/somevalue2.txt`

`somevalueX -> /somevalueX/path-hdfs/somevalueX.txt`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Right now theres no out of the box descision for that, but theres [pull request](https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/1044) for HDFS Bolt improvement, which allows write in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple HDFS bolts (one for each file) and emit different output streams in the producer bolt that feed the HDFS bolts.

For this, declare an output stream for each output file in the producer bolt, and emit the tuples to the corresponding output stream in `execute(...)` method.